# QStyleItemDelegate with Custom Buttons

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a QTreeWidget and I want to fully customize the way the items look by using a style delegate.

My main issue is that I would like to create a custom button, on the right of my Item, that allows me to collapse and expand the children of that item. The classical "+" button that can be usually found on the left side of most Trees.

I have no problem to paint the button itself, and change its icon depending if the item is expanded or not. The problem is to make it behave like a button ( Activate a command when is pressed, change color when hovered etc..)

What I came up with is to use the **editorEvent** to check if the mouse has been pressed on the same position as where I draw the button of the current item.

To obtain an hover effect, I edited the **mouseMoveEvent** of my tree and checked if the mouse is on top of a the button of the item, and if so, repaint the item with the hover on.

My implementation does the job, but I am concerned  that I did it completely wrong, without being efficient and that my tree is going to be slow because of this kind of calculation. So I was wondering, if anyone had some suggestions on how to improve the code below.

The Delegate

```
class styleDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):


    def __init__(self, parent=None, treeWidget = None):
        super(styleDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tree = treeWidget      

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        painter.save()
        rect = option.rect

        # set the pen to draw an outline around the item to divide them.
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(43, 43, 43))
        pen.setWidthF(1)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        item = self.tree.itemFromIndex(index)

        # set the background color based on the item or if it is selected
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.setBrush(option.palette.highlight())
        else:
            color = item.color
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(color[0] * 255, color[1] * 255, color[2] * 255))

        #draw the colored background 
        painter.drawRect(rect)

        #draw the image
        imageScale = 0
        margin = 4
        imageScale = rect.height() - margin * 2 + 1
        painter.drawPixmap(rect.x() + margin, rect.y() + margin , imageScale, imageScale, item.image.scaled(imageScale, imageScale, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))

        # draw the text 

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        font = painter.font()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        painter.setFont(font)

        painter.drawText(rect.x() + imageScale + margin * 3, rect.y(), 100, item.scale, Qt.AlignVCenter, item.name)

        # draw the expander button only if the item has children
        if item.childCount():

            # choose the appropriate icon to draw depending on the state of the item.
            if item.isExpanded():
                path = "checked.png"
                if item.hover:
                    path = "checked_hover.png"
            else:
                path = "unchecked.png"
                if item.hover:
                    path = "unchecked_hover.png"
            image = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(QtGui.QImage(path))
            size = 20 

            # define the position of the expander button

            positionX = rect.x() + rect.width() - 20 
            positionY = rect.y() + item.scale / 2 - size/2

            painter.drawPixmap(positionX, positionY, size, size, image.scaled(size, size, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))

            item.expanderStart = QPoint(positionX, positionY)
            item.expanderEnd = QPoint(positionX + 20, positionY + 20)

        painter.restore() 

   def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):


        # if an item is clicked, check if the click happened in the area whee the expander button is drawn.
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            item = self.tree.itemFromIndex(index)

            rect = option.rect
            clickX = event.x()
            clickY = event.y()

            # set the expanded expanded if it was clicked
            if  clickX > x and clickX < x + w:
                if clickY > y and clickY < y + h:
                    item.setExpanded(not item.isExpanded())
```

The Tree

```
class myTree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(myTree, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
        item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        if item:
            if item.childCount():
                # get the current hovering state. if the item is already hovered, there is no need to repaint it. 
                hover = item.hover
                if (event.pos.x() > item.expanderStart.x()
                    and event.pos.x() < item.expanderEnd.x()
                    and event.pos.y() > item.expanderStart.y()
                    and event.pos.y() < item.expanderEnd.y())
                    item.hover = True
                else:
                    item.hover = False
                if item.hover != hover:
                    self.viewport().update(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y(), 20, 20)
```

I know this can be fully achieved without using delegates, by simply working with Stylesheets or assigning a widget to the Item. However, I didn't get to far with these methods, since I got several problems with them.

I spent loads of time trying to achieve the result I want without success. Maybe I get my Items to look close to what I Want, but never exactly as I imagine them.

The reason I am being so fussy on getting exactly the look I have in mind with delegates is that this QTreeWidget was once a QListWidget, implemented with stylesheets. Now that I am "updgrading" it to a Tree I don't want the user to even notice the difference, but i was not able to replicate the same exact look with sylesheets alone.

Pardon me if the code above has stupid mistake, I have tested the full version and it was working, and I just posted here the relevant stuff.

---

EDIT:

As requested, this is some code that (At least to me) produces the desired result. However, I wonder if this is the correct way of doing what im doing or not...

```
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class styleDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):


    def __init__(self, parent=None, treeWidget = None):
        super(styleDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tree = treeWidget      

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        painter.save()
        rect = option.rect

        # set the pen to draw an outline around the item to divide them.
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setBrush(QColor(43, 43, 43))
        pen.setWidthF(1)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        item = self.tree.itemFromIndex(index)

        # set the background color based on the item or if it is selected
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.setBrush(option.palette.highlight())
        else:
            color = item.color
            painter.setBrush(QColor(color[0], color[1], color[2]))

        #draw the colored background 
        painter.drawRect(rect)

        #draw the image
        margin = 4
        imageScale = rect.height() - margin * 2 + 1
        painter.drawPixmap(rect.x() + margin, rect.y() + margin , imageScale, imageScale, item.image.scaled(imageScale, imageScale, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))

        # draw the text 

        painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        font = painter.font()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        painter.setFont(font)

        painter.drawText(rect.x() + imageScale + margin * 3, rect.y(), 300, item.scale, Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter, item.name)

        # draw the expander button only if the item has children
        if item.childCount():

            # choose the appropriate icon to draw depending on the state of the item.
            if item.isExpanded():
                path = "c:\\test.png"
                if item.hover:
                    path = "c:\\test.png"
            else:
                path = "c:\\test.png"
                if item.hover:
                    path = "c:\\test.png"
            image = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(path))
            size = self.tree.expanderSize

            # define the position of the expander button

            positionX = rect.x() + rect.width() - size - 10
            positionY = rect.y() + item.scale / 2 - size/2

            painter.drawPixmap(positionX, positionY, size, size, image.scaled(size, size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))

            item.expanderStart = QPoint(positionX, positionY)
            item.expanderEnd = QPoint(positionX + size, positionY + size)

        painter.restore() 

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):


        # if an item is clicked, check if the click happened in the area whee the expander button is drawn.
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            item = self.tree.itemFromIndex(index)
            if item.childCount():
                rect = option.rect
                clickX = event.x()
                clickY = event.y()
                size = self.tree.expanderSize
                # this is the rect of the expander button
                x = rect.x() + rect.width() - 20 
                y = rect.y() + item.scale / 2 - size/2
                w = size # expander width
                h = size # expander height
                # set the expanded expanded if it was clicked
                if (clickX > item.expanderStart.x()
                    and clickX < item.expanderEnd.x()
                    and clickY > item.expanderStart.y()
                    and clickY < item.expanderEnd.y()):
                    print "expand"
                    item.setExpanded(not item.isExpanded())


class myTree(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(myTree, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        if item:
            if item.childCount():
                # get the current hovering state. if the item is already hovered, there is no need to repaint it. 
                hover = item.hover
                if (event.pos() .x() > item.expanderStart.x()
                    and event.pos() .x() < item.expanderEnd.x()
                    and event.pos() .y() > item.expanderStart.y()
                    and event.pos() .y() < item.expanderEnd.y()):
                    item.hover = True
                else:
                    item.hover = False
                if item.hover != hover:
                    self.viewport().update(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y(), 20, 20)     
                    print "Hover", item.hover  
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.deleteLater()

def generateTree():
    tree = myTree()
    tree.setGeometry(500, 500, 1000, 500)
    tree.expanderSize = 50
    delegate = styleDelegate(tree, treeWidget = tree)
    tree.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    for object in ["Aaaaaaa", "Bbbbbbb", "Ccccccc"]:
        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        item.name = object
        item.image = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage("c:\\test.png"))
        item.color = [150, 150, 150]
        item.hover = False
        item.scale = 100
        tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
        item.setSizeHint(0, QSize(item.scale, item.scale ))
        for child in ["Eeeeee", "Fffffff"]:
            childItem = QTreeWidgetItem()
            childItem.name = child
            childItem.image = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage("c:\\test.png"))
            childItem.color = [150, 150, 150]
            childItem.scale = 90

            item.addChild(childItem)
            childItem.setSizeHint(0, QSize(childItem.scale, childItem.scale))
    return tree

tree = generateTree()    
tree.show()
```

Note that my monitor is 4k and I quickly Hardcoded most of the sizes, so out of the box this code will produce much bigger widgets on a HD monitor.

Comment: please save our time and provide a [mcve]

Comment: what is `mode`, what is `color`, etc?

Comment: `mode` is something i should have removed. As mentioned in the post, I stripped away all what is not relevant to the topic, and something was still there.

Comment: Eliminate everything that is not relevant but please show a complete code thus saving us time that we can invest in giving you a better solution.

Comment: `image` `color` `name` are variable that I set when creating each item. I didn't add as well the creation of the Widget itself because i thought it was not relevant, since i am more interested in knowing if the method used makes sense rather than if it just works

Comment: I am going to get a full working code, give me 5 minutes. =)

Comment: It's great to say that, but believe it, the creation of the widget is relevant because it saves time for example I have to invest some time to create the data that meets the requirements of your code, do not you think it's better to invest my time in help you in the central problem and not in patching code to make it workable ?, have you read that it is a [mcve] and its importance? If you have not done so, read the link, please :-)

Comment: As you can see I am new to stackOverflow, and I completely missed that page =D I am reading it now. 

How would I provide images for you to use in the code? of course if I hardcode a path it won't work for others.

Comment: the image files are irrelevant, I can place the icons that I have, the main thing is the code, this must be complete and verifiable, the minimum is the easiest since it is only delete code mainly. great if you are reading the link.

Comment: I am working on it right now

Comment: great, let me know when you've done it

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for the wait, it took a bit more because I am on my laptop and I had no code that I could use as a base and had to write it down again.

I updated the original post with some working code. I hope is ok

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: I was running the code above directly from Maya, where I will need to use the UI.
According to Autodesk docs
"PySide version 2.0 is included with Maya. It is built with Python 2.7 and Maya Qt version 5.6.1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- It is not necessary to use `QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(path))`, you can create a `QPixmap` directly with the path: `QPixmap(path)`
- If they are the same images, it is better to load it once and reuse it, for example in my solution I do it for the buttons QPixmap.
- Do not create dynamic attributes because it generates code coupling, in the case of items you must use the roles.
- To know if an item is expanded or you should not use `QStyle::State_Open` so we avoid coupling and the delegate can be used by other views without making many changes.
- Use `QRect` to delimit a rectangle and so for example you use contains to see if a point is inside the rectangle.

The above are the main observations, in the following part is the solution:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from enum import Enum  

ScaleRole= QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1
expanderSize = 50


class TreeDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pixmap_collapsed =  QtGui.QPixmap("collapsed.png")
        self.pixmap_collapsed_hover = QtGui.QPixmap("collapsed_hover.png")
        self.pixmap_expanded = QtGui.QPixmap("expanded.png")
        self.pixmap_expanded_hover = QtGui.QPixmap("expanded_hover.png")

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        image = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        scale = index.data(ScaleRole)
        name = index.data()

        painter.save()
        rect = option.rect
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(brush=QtGui.QColor(43, 43, 43), widthF=1))
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.setBrush(option.palette.highlight())
        else:
            painter.setBrush(index.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole))
        painter.drawRect(rect)

        margin = 4
        image_scale = (rect.height() - margin * 2 + 1)*QtCore.QSize(1, 1)
        if image is not None and not image.isNull():
            image = image.scaled(image_scale, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            painter.drawPixmap(rect.topLeft() + margin*QtCore.QPoint(1, 1), image)

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        font = painter.font()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(QtCore.QRect(rect.topLeft() + QtCore.QPoint(image_scale.width() + 3*margin, 0) , QtCore.QSize(300, scale)), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, name)

        if index.model().hasChildren(index):
            pixmap = self.pixmap_collapsed
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open:
                if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver:
                    pixmap = self.pixmap_expanded_hover
                else:
                    pixmap = self.pixmap_expanded
            else :
                if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver:
                    pixmap = self.pixmap_collapsed_hover
            size = expanderSize
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(size*QtCore.QSize(1, 1), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            pos = rect.topRight() - QtCore.QPoint(size+10, (size-scale)/2)
            painter.drawPixmap(pos, pixmap)
        painter.restore()


class MyTreeItem(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, name, image, color, scale):
        super(MyTreeItem, self).__init__([name])
        self.setData(0, ScaleRole, scale)
        self.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, color)
        self.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole, image)


class MyTree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTree, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        if not self.itemsExpandable(): return
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if not index.isValid(): return
        # restore state
        is_expanded = self.isExpanded(index)
        QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        self.setExpanded(index, is_expanded)

        if not self.model().hasChildren(index): return
        rect = self.visualRect(index)
        size = expanderSize
        scale = index.data(ScaleRole)
        pos = rect.topRight() - QtCore.QPoint(size+10, (size-scale)/2)
        r = QtCore.QRect(pos, size*QtCore.QSize(1, 1))
        if r.contains(event.pos()):
            self.setExpanded(index, not self.isExpanded(index))


def generate_tree():
    tree = MyTree()
    scale = 100
    delegate = TreeDelegate(tree)
    tree.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    for text in ["Aaaaaaa", "Bbbbbbb", "Ccccccc"]:
        item = MyTreeItem(text, QtGui.QPixmap("image.png"), QtGui.QColor(150, 150, 150), scale)
        item.setSizeHint(0, QtCore.QSize(scale, scale))
        tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
        for child in ["Eeeeee", "Fffffff"]:
            childItem = MyTreeItem(child, QtGui.QPixmap("image.png"), QtGui.QColor(150, 150, 150), scale)
            childItem.setSizeHint(0, QtCore.QSize(scale, scale))
            item.addChild(childItem)
    return tree


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tree = generate_tree()    
    tree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my code and for giving all these suggestions. So the way I implemented my tree is correct, on a logical point of view? Would it be possible to replicate the same result with stylesheet or other methods or delegates are the best way in this scenario?

Comment: @Yagalos your initial logic is correct in part, if you check my answer there are suggestions for improvement that apply to my solution, check my solution to get more details, if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it check the [tour ], that's the best way to thank.

Comment: @Yagalos There is no better way, there is a convenient way, implement the same with Qt Style Sheet would be a complicated task, I do not think you get the same result so given your requirements it is convenient to use delegates.

Comment: Also I think I am not familiar with the terminology "code coupling". I never had a proper education in good coding practices, so I am sure my way of dealing with things is quite amatorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes me feel less worried that at least the idea behind it is not formally wrong. I am trying to understand how to write code that is not a bunch of mess, but is taking time since I still miss quite a lot of the best practices. I will accept your answer, thanks a lot for dedicating me time

Comment: @Yagalos That concept is more for the creation of libraries, for example take the example of QStyledItemDelegate, that class can be set as a delegate of QTreeView, QTableView, QTreeWidget, QTableWidget, QListView, QListWidget without difference, ie the delegate does not care which of the views is always working, but in your initial code the delegate is highly dependent on QTreeWidget so if you want to set it in a QTreeView or another view you will have to write a lot of code, but with my solution the delegate does not depend on the view or of the type of model but of model information

Comment: @Yagalos The improvement of the code is very dependent on practice, the more you write software, the more concepts you will learn, check other answers and review the style of programming, there you will learn the concepts in a practical way.

Comment: I understand, thanks. I have mostly worked with Qt as a side tool to develop UI for my tools at work, so most of the times I was just worrying about the code working out of the box rather than performing well or being well design. The more I work, and I have to edit my old code, the more I am becoming interesting on learning how to do things properly, since I noticed that doing things randomly just results in me having to do extra work later anyway to fix things when i do a change.

Comment: @Yagalos A good developer not only cares because the code works well but always works well.

Comment: One last question, if you have time.

Comment: In my original code, I have added a lot of extra functions and variables to my QTrewWidgetItem that are completely unrelated to Qt. Let's say each item would correspond  to a file, I added inside variables and functions to know the size/location/format etc of this file. By doing this, by simply grabbing an item I can reach the info about the file by doing something like "item.fileSize" that will return the size of the file. I saw you removed all the custom variables I created for my item like "name", "Color"... Does this mean my practice of storing info in the item class is wrong?

Comment: @Yagalos You must store that type of data in the model using the roles.